# website custom audience audience is too small

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am using Facebook graph api v2.8 and following steps I have done.

- Created website custom audience and specified my website home URL in it.
- installed Facebook pixel on my website home page and below that called 
  `fbq('track', 'ViewContent', {
    content_name: id,
    content_ids: [id],`
  Here id = custom audience id
- for all users I pass same custom audience id. Why I am passing custom audience id because I want to track for that particular audience and I don't have visitor data like name, email etc
- Now pixel fires are increasing but I still see "Audience is too small"

Going further in detail. I noticed my ad account is not included in Ads API in APP and I see following in my app

[image]

When I see in graph API explorer then I see following error.

> (#274) The ad account is not enabled for usage in Ads API. Please add
>   it in developers.facebook.com/apps -> select your app -> settings ->
>   advanced -> advertising accounts -> Ads API. Account 
>   not enabled for this application.

I have Following permissions.

- Ads Management API Standard Access
- Ads Management API basic Access
- Business management

Any suggestions, where I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have explored it further and added one screen shot in question

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience#Creating, you need to have at least 200 different users to create a website custom audience. Do you have so many users visiting your website? (Actual user, minus those who do not have Facebook accounts, minus those who have not logged in Facebook yet.)

The "content_ids" is not "custom audience id". That parameter is used to report to Facebook about which product on your website has been seen by the user, so that Facebook can show the proper product in the Dynamic Ads, if you create one. That parameter has nothing to do with the custom audience creation.

You keep on seeing the audience size too small, probably because 1) you do not have enough visitors as I asked above, or 2) the pixel code is not fired properly (you can debug it with a Chrome extension "Pixel Helper"), or 3) the website custom audience rule is not set properly, like instead of "url contains john.com", you have "url is john.com".